# Send visit to URL while opening another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've multiple urls in the same page... For some urls I need to open them in new tab and at the same time send send a "visit" / request to another url...

```
<a href="<URL TO OPEN IN NEW TAB>" data-uri="<URL TO SEND VISIT TO>">Text</a>
```

I'm searching for a way to achieve this, and be able to send a request to all link which contain data-uri ...

do you guys think it's possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using jquery ajax.
For example.
 When the link has been clicked it open in another tab and request another link with in data-uri.

```
$('a').click(function(){
 var vLink = $(this).attr('data-uri');
 $.ajax({
  url: vLink,
  data: '',
  Type: 'GET',
  success:function(res){
   //notify that the link is visited.
   alert('the link is visited');
  },
  error:function(err){
   alert(err.message);
  }
 });
});
```

The link in attribute "data-uri" will be visited.

Comment: thank you very much. that's exactly what I needed :)

Comment: You are wellcome. All the best.